# Unwanted indentation after `\allowdisplaybreak`

Tags: indentation

The input below creates (unwanted) indentation after the display:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\allowdisplaybreaks 
\begin{align*} 
a_n&=b_n\\&>0
\end{align*}}       
so the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing. We conclude that it converges, and by passing  
\end{document}
```

The indentation disappears if I insert a blank line and `\indent` after the display, but it adds extra space. Is there a clean way of not having the indentation?

Comment: You can mark your code in the question as code by selecting it and hitting the "{}" button (or indenting it by 4 spaces). For inline code you should enclose it with `\``. I made these changes to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is added because you didn't escape the end of line after the closing brace of your group around the `align*` environment (you didn't put a `%` there). The following gives ordinary spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
{\allowdisplaybreaks 
\begin{align*} 
a_n&=b_n\\&>0
\end{align*}}%
so the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing. We conclude that it converges, and by passing  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively use `\begingroup\allowdisplaybreaks...\endgroup`